# Is Zotero's Firefox installation computer specific?

Tags: firefox, browser, zotero

I use [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) (3.0.3) in my Firefox browser (8.0). I have built a large inventory of literature over a one year period which is quite valuable to me. That inventory is synced with Zotero's online server, but the inventory saved with their server on their webpage under `My Library` is not as interactive and convenient as their browser based tool which is shown in following snapshot:

[image]

My concern is that I believe this browser based tool (the one in above snapshot) is computer specific. I am not sure if I change a computer whether I would still be able to access my literature with all the folders and files in similar fashion as I have with Zotero in my present computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read Zotero's documentation](http://www.zotero.org/support/sync), make sure both data syncing and file syncing have been configured, and you should be fine. Get access to another computer and test!

Comment: Or just create a second Firefox profile.